# how to keep result open after commiting the connection in jdbc with mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using jdbc with mysql and using the transcation. In

```
while(resultset.hasnext()){}
```

while I commit the connection my resultset become closed, and when 2nd time loop iterates, it throws Exception that operation can not be performed on closed resultset. While I also set these parameters

```
statement1 = connection1.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
```

but I am unable to keep ResultSet open after a commit.

```
while(resultSet.next()){        
    id=resultSet.getInt(1);
     c1 = resultSet.getString(2);
     c2 = resultSet.getDate(3);
     c3 = resultSet.getString(4);
     c4 = resultSet.getString(5);
     c5 = resultSet.getString(6);
     c6 = resultSet.getString(7);
     c7 = resultSet.getString(8);
     c8 = resultSet.getString(9);
     c9 = resultSet.getString(10);
     c10 = resultSet.getString(11);
     c11 = resultSet.getString(12);
     c12 = resultSet.getString(13);
     c13 = resultSet.getString(14);
     c14 = resultSet.getDate(15);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, c1);
    preparedStatement.setDate(2, c2);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, c3);
    preparedStatement.setString(4, c4);
    preparedStatement.setString(5, c5);
    preparedStatement.setString(6, c6);
    preparedStatement.setString(7, c7);
    preparedStatement.setString(8, c8);
    preparedStatement.setString(9, c9);
    preparedStatement.setString(10, c10);
    preparedStatement.setString(11, c11);
    preparedStatement.setString(12, c12);
    preparedStatement.setString(13, c13);
    preparedStatement.setDate(14, c14);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    query = "UPDATE abc SET isUpdated = 1 WHERE abc_id= "+id;
    statement1.executeUpdate(query);
    System.out.println("holdablity... "+resultSet.getHoldability());
    connection1.commit();
    System.out.println(connection1+"and result is====="+resultSet+" result status is "+resultSet.isClosed()+" connection1 is  "+connection1.isClosed());
    System.out.println("holdablity... "+resultSet.getHoldability());
    connection2.commit();
    System.out.println(connection1+"and result is====="+resultSet+" result status is "+resultSet.isClosed()+" connection2 is  "+connection2.isClosed());
    System.out.println("Data copied........");

    }
```

Comment: Please include your code

Comment: You should save the results into an object.  You are having this issue probably because you call resultset.close()

Comment: i m  not closing resultset explicitly......

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb and Eran code is available....

Comment: Why? It doesn't make sense. The update has been committed. A microsecond later, all that data could haven't been changed, or deleted, or invalidated as a query result, by some other process. Why do you think you want to keep access to stale data?

Comment: @EJP update is commited for the first row only. when it comes for the second row it throws exception...

Comment: You need to read the Javadoc. The result set is invalidated by the update. You should be building a batch here, not committing row by row.

Comment: You also need to consider my first comment. There is a major concurrency problem in what you're trying to do. This isn't just a coding issue.

Answer (score -2):

Once you have have committed the transaction, the result set will automatically be closed. Commit method is like telling all the insertion/update has been successfully done. So it closes the result set.
Few alternative ways i can suggest inorder to achieve the same is,
 1. Dump the result set data into some collection classes so that you can retrieve or fetch the data from it at any point. Even when the transaction has been committed and resultSet has been closed.
 2. You can first make autocommit property to be true. Then you can call a stored procedure inside the loop of iteration of resultset and make that procedure commit the result if there's no error in it. In this way your result set will be open and data has been committed via procedure.
Any way you choose . You have to work around anyhow.

Comment: i can not take the risk of setAutoCommit true, because i have both DataBases on different locations and i have to make sure the data is transfered successfuly and then to mark it otherwise roleback in any case like network faliure or ETC...

Comment: I would recommend the first alternative. That should work fine.

Comment: @EJP :- So what is the solution if he wants to retrieve the result set data even after committing and indirectly closing the transaction??    what you are saying we already know that, be a part of solution not a part of problem

Comment: thanks all of you. I do it by using the list but still i don,t know why my ResultSet is becoming closed after a commit....

Comment: That was the first alternative that i had suggested you.
You are welcome :)